# Which is the differential $\text{d} p_i$ of a generalized momentum?

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, differentiation, calculus

I want to get a partition function, but I introduce a generalized momentum, my doubt is about, when I define a differential respect to $p$, it means $\text{d} p$, which is the correct form to get it?

For example, from this Hamiltonian, I have:

$$ H = \frac{1}{2} m r^2 [ \dot{\theta}^2 + \sin^2( \theta) \dot{\phi}^2 ]
$$

where

$$p_\phi = mr^2 \sin^2( \theta) \dot{\phi}$$

So, is $\text{d} p_\phi$ just $\text{d} p_\phi$, or is it $mr \sin( \theta) d p_\phi$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$dp_{\phi}$ is just $dp_{\phi}$. However, if you want to represent $dp_{\phi}$ with other variables, you can use the equation $p_{\phi} = mr^2 \sin^2(\theta) \dot{\phi}$.

Comment: Thanks for clarification